# Нужен ли второй defer file.Close(), после перезаписи переменной?

Tags: golang

Например, есть такой код:

```
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("referenceData/ex.json")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer jsonFile.Close() // первый defer
    byteValue, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &exToParse)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    jsonFile, err = os.Open("referenceData/di.json") // перезапись jsonFile
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer jsonFile.Close() // нужно ли заново объявлять defer jsonFile.Close()?
    byteValue, err = ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &diToParse)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Сначала инициализирую переменную не через `var`, а сразу передаю значение. Потом сразу пишу `defer jsonFile.Close()`

Потом в этот же файл загружаю другой json, и так же пишу `defer jsonFile.Close()`.

Вопрос - а нужен ли второй `defer`? По идеи в ОЗУ, после  перезаписи, `jsonFile` один и тоже, с тем же адресом, но только с другим содержанием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, нужен, так как аргументы функции, вызываемой
`defer`, вычисляются в момент использования
`defer`. Можете увидеть в подобном
простом примере:

```golang
type T int

func (t T) Close() { fmt.Println(int(t)) }

// …

t := T(1)
defer t.Close()

t = T(2)
defer t.Close()
```

```
2
1
```

И вообще не рекомендую переиспользовать переменные подобным
образом, так как это усложняет понимание текста программы.

---

<sup>Ну и вдогонку. Не так:</sup>

```golang
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
// Check err.
err = json.Unmarshal(b, &v)
// Check err.
```

<sup>А так:</sup>

```golang
err = json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&v)
// Check err.
```